# Résumé formality: "Struck a deal that resulted in savings of XXX"?

Tags: expressions

I am not sure if the paragraph below is a bit too casual for a résumé:

> - Responsible for negotiating the purchase of XXX. Struck a business deal that resulted in savings of 12,000 EUR/month

Is there a more formal way of saying "Struck a business deal?" in a CV? I am concerned it may sound too colloquial.

Comment: Resulted in savings to whom?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Struck a deal" is too idiomatic for a résumé; perhaps *negotiated an agreement* or *mediated an arrangement* would be more fitting.

Answer (score 2):

You likely ***negotiated*** a deal or arranged a deal.

Answer (score 2):

Or perhaps

> brokered

, depending on the type/context of the deal.

Answer (score 2):

***Closed***

> Responsible for negotiating the purchase of XXX. Successfully closing the business deal resulted in savings of 12,000 EUR/month to my company.

I have heard in business lingo the word *closed* implying successful closure of a deal.

[**close a deal** and **close the deal**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/close+a+deal)
to formally conclude bargaining; to bring negotiating to an end by reaching an agreement.
*We negotiated the terms of the agreement, and this afternoon we will close the deal.*

The free dictionary merely says *to conclude*. However in actual usage, it is understood as sort of 'successfully clinched' a deal.